# Assembly Motorola 68k, how to branch if a tested bit is zero?

Tags: assembly, branch, 68000

I am writing a program in assembly using easy68k, I was looking for a way to make a branch if a tested bit is equal to zero [Z=0 in SR].

I searched a lot but didn't get an answer,

for example, I have this line:

```
  BTST #0,D2 ;Testing the LSB bit in data register 0
```

Now I want a way, or if there exists, an instruction to check Z in the SR, so I can know if the tested bit is zero or not.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever, I saw that before, but the ones that use Z which is BEQ, BNE seems not useful as I see that they are for comparison which am not doing here, am not comparing two values.
Isn't there any instruction to move a single defined bit to a data register ?

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever
So I can use the instruction `BEQ` without operands and it will branch based on `Z` value ?
Or should I put any operands without using them ? But doing that will re-affect the `Z` value, right ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The instruction to test condition codes and branch based on them is generically referred to as [`Bcc`](http://68k.hax.com/Bcc). The individual names for these conditional branch instructions are based on what they would mean if the immediately preceding instruction was [`CMP`](http://68k.hax.com/CMP).

But, by themselves, all they do is test a condition code and take the branch. So, you can do:

```
BTST #0,D2 ;Testing the LSB bit in data register 0
BEQ LabelForZSet
;Code for Z clear
```

Answer (score 1):

Branch on Z-Flag:

```
btst #0,d2
beq bitIsCleared
; or
bne bitIsSet
```

Z-Flag to register:

```
btst #0,d2
sne  d0
; d0 (byte only) will now be 0xFF if bit was set, 0x00 otherwise)
; if a word is required add ext.w d0
; if a long is required add also ext.l d0
```